# Starting Calibration with openni_tracker

Tags: kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What pose do you need to hit in order for openni_tracker to start its calibration? When I've used it, it will sometimes recognize a Psi-pose and then not calibrate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9599/starting-calibration-with-openni_tracker/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you need to stay in the Psi pose.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2